# xamarin ios save uiimage to a web server

Tags: xamarin.ios, uiimage

I am using Xamarin and am trying to save an UIImage picked from a camera roll or taken from a camera and save it to my web server.

It is a monotouch shared project  (It's my first crack at using Xamarin and didn't know all the ways to do things like Portable or Forms) so Plugin.Media won't work.

My existing code is

```
private async void SaveImage()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        var client = new HttpClient();

        using (NSData imgData = imgFood.Image.AsJPEG())
        {
            Byte[] imageByte = new Byte[imgData.Length];
            HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(imageByte);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.myWebserver.com/myWebDir", content);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
    }
}
```

My image from camera roll test byte.Length = 171733
Stepping through the code it hits the Post line then jumps to where I called this method ignoring any lines below it and no image is saved to my godaddy web server.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is there an actual problem?  The behavior you're describing is because you're debugging async code.  That does not mean that the POST isn't actually occurring.

Comment: when i look at my web server no image is saved

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Are you getting a response from the server?  Is the server receiving the request?  Is the server throwing an error?  Have you checked the server logs?  These are all basic debugging steps.

Comment: no errors are caught by try catch.
I've try printing the response to console but it completly jumps past all of that and goes to the line after where i call the method.

Comment: Well, that would point me towards a problem on the server.  What is running on the server to handle the file upload?  Have you checked it's logs?

Comment: my androiod version uses a php file to upload you mean something like that? i havent checked the logs
i use
             byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("http://biteboard.ca/php/savePic.php", "POST", _file.Path);

Comment: Yes, whatever code or script is running on your server to handle the uploaded file.  Why don't you use the same upload logic for both Android and iOS?

Comment: one reason is android uses a string for the path and ios use nsurl, the line i posted uses a string for file.path. so in short android and ios are inherintly different for commands like this. the php is the same but getting there is different. unless you can point me to the proper ios syntax.

Comment: How about trying `var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(); var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageByte);imageContent.Headers.ContentType =     MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");requestContent.Add(imageContent, "image", "image.jpg");client.PostAsync(url, requestContent);`

Comment: if HttpClient.UploadFile() works on Android it should work on iOS.  That is a .NET class, not a platform class.  And IF you do choose to use PostAsync instead on iOS, then you will probably need a different method on your server to receive the upload.